# How to have sub functions in a class

Tags: c++

With a subfunction I mean that given a class `A` and instance `a`, I can call

```
a.control.fire();
```

Where control is some type of struct containing functions. However, an additionall requirement is that `fire()` can access variables of `a`. I have tried the following:

```
#pragma once

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    double c;

    struct Controller {
        double fire () { return c * 2};
    };

    Controller control;

    A();
};
```

Now I can indeed call `a.control.fire()` but it gives an error on trying to access `c`. How can I solve this?

Comment: Give the Controller a reference to the parent object as part of its construction.

Comment: This cannot work if `control` doesn't have a link/pointer/reference to `a` in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

[Nested classes on cpprefrence.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types)

> Like any member of its enclosing class, the nested class has access to all names (private, protected, etc) to which the enclosing class has access, ***but it is*** otherwise ***independent*** and has no special access to the `this` pointer of the enclosing class.

C++ does not create an instance of the *inner* class when the *outer* class is created. Nor does the *inner* class gain any variables which allow it to use the *outer* classes variables. The classes have to explicitly declare access to each other (for example by instantiations, references or pointers).

So the `Controller` needs 2 things :

- the reference to the variable c or an instantiation of it's class: `double& ref_c` or `A& a`
- a constructor which initializes `ref_c` or `a`

Then in `A`'s constructor `controller` needs to be initialized with `c` or `*this` (aggregate initialization can also be used).

---

*Example:*

```
class Outer // Enclosing
{
public:
    double c;

    struct Inner // Nested
    {
        const Outer& a;

        double fire() const { return a.c * 2; };
    };

    Inner control { *this };

    Outer();
};
```

Answer (score -2):

There are two watertight containers inside of `class A`: `double c` and `struct Controller`. From inside of one you cannot get to the other. The rule in C++ layers of abstraction is that you cannot go from the inside out. You can only go from the outside in. `Controller::fire()` can only see stuff inside the `Controller` itself. It has no knowledge of the outside world.

You can improve your code by getting rid of the `Controller` all together. It is a "wall" which prevents your function from seeing the `double c` because it is sitting inside that wall:

```
    #pragma once

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    double c;

    double fire () { return c * 2};


    A();
};
```

The other way to do it would be to provide some "door" through the "wall", some kind of mechanism to get the `double c` into the `Controller` to make it visible to the `double fire()`. I mean declare a constructor `Controller::Controller()` and pass a pointer in.

```
#pragma once

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    double c;

    struct Controller {
        Controller(double* ptr) : c_ptr(ptr) {}
        double * c_ptr;
        double fire () { return *c_ptr * 2};
    };

    Controller control(&c);

    A();
};
```

As mentioned in another answer, you can also use references in C++. That would actually be even better in this situation.

```
#pragma once

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    double c;

    struct Controller {
        Controller(double& input) : c(input) {}
        double& c;
        double fire () { return c * 2};
    };

    Controller control(c);

    A();
};
```